# Visualization of the filters of VGG16

Tags: python-3.x, keras, visualization, deconvolution, conv-neural-network

I am learning CNN, right now, working on deconvolution of the layers. I have begun the process of learning upsampling and observe how convolution layers see the world by generating feature maps from the filters from the source [Visualization of the filters of VGG16](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html), with the [Source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py). I have changed the input and the code is as follows:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import time
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras import backend as K

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# dimensions of the generated pictures for each filter.
img_width = 128
img_height = 128

# the name of the layer we want to visualize
# (see model definition at keras/applications/vgg16.py)
layer_name = 'block5_conv1'

# util function to convert a tensor into a valid image


def deprocess_image(x):
    # normalize tensor: center on 0., ensure std is 0.1
    x -= x.mean()
    x /= (x.std() + K.epsilon())
    x *= 0.1

    # clip to [0, 1]
    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)

    # convert to RGB array
    x *= 255
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        x = x.transpose((1, 2, 0))
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x

# build the VGG16 network with ImageNet weights
model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print('Model loaded.')

model.summary()

# this is the placeholder for the input images
input_img = model.input

# get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[1:]])


def normalize(x):
    # utility function to normalize a tensor by its L2 norm
    return x / (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(x))) + K.epsilon())


kept_filters = []
for filter_index in range(200):
    # we only scan through the first 200 filters,
    # but there are actually 512 of them
    print('Processing filter %d' % filter_index)
    start_time = time.time()

    # we build a loss function that maximizes the activation
    # of the nth filter of the layer considered
    layer_output = layer_dict[layer_name].output
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, filter_index, :, :])
    else:
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

    # we compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
    grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

    # normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
    grads = normalize(grads)

    # this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
    iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])

    # step size for gradient ascent
    step = 1.

    inpImgg = '/home/sanaalamgeer/Downloads/cat.jpeg'
    inpImg = mpimg.imread(inpImgg)
    inpImg = cv2.resize(inpImg, (img_width, img_height))        

    # we start from a gray image with some random noise
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_img_data = inpImg.reshape((1, 3, img_width, img_height))
    else:
        input_img_data = inpImg.reshape((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
    input_img_data = (input_img_data - 0.5) * 20 + 128

    # we run gradient ascent for 20 steps
    for i in range(20):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step

        print('Current loss value:', loss_value)
        if loss_value <= 0.:
            # some filters get stuck to 0, we can skip them
            break

    # decode the resulting input image
    if loss_value > 0:
        img = deprocess_image(input_img_data[0])
        kept_filters.append((img, loss_value))
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Filter %d processed in %ds' % (filter_index, end_time - start_time))

# we will stich the best 64 filters on a 8 x 8 grid.
n = 8

# the filters that have the highest loss are assumed to be better-looking.
# we will only keep the top 64 filters.
kept_filters.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
kept_filters = kept_filters[:n * n]

# build a black picture with enough space for
# our 8 x 8 filters of size 128 x 128, with a 5px margin in between
margin = 5
width = n * img_width + (n - 1) * margin
height = n * img_height + (n - 1) * margin
stitched_filters = np.zeros((width, height, 3))

# fill the picture with our saved filters
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        img, loss = kept_filters[i * n + j]
        stitched_filters[(img_width + margin) * i: (img_width + margin) * i + img_width,
                         (img_height + margin) * j: (img_height + margin) * j + img_height, :] = img

# save the result to disk
imageio.imwrite('stitched_filters_%dx%d.png' % (n, n), stitched_filters)
```

The input image I am using is [image: cat.jpg]

It is supposed to generate an output with 64 feature maps embedded into one image as shown in [Visualization of the filters of VGG16](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html), but it is generating the same input image at each filter, 
[image: wrong output].

I am confused what's wrong or where I should make changes.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a complex code....

I'd do this:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
layer_name = 'block5_conv1'

#create a section of the model to output the layer we want
model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model = Model(model.input, model.get_layer(layer_name).output)

#open and preprocess the cat image
catImage = openTheCatImage(catFile)
catImage = np.expand_dims(catImage,axis=0)
catImage = preprocess_input(catImage)

#get the layer outputs
features = model.predict(catImage)

#plot
for channel in range(features.shape[-1]): #or .shape[1], or up to a limit you like 
    featureMap = features[:,:,:,channel] #or features[:,channel]
    featureMap = deprocess_image(feature_map)[0]

    saveOrPlot(featureMap)
```

Comment: ´catImage = preprocess_input(catImage)´ is giving error ´ValueError: output array is read-only´

Comment: interesting, could you test changing the name of the var. like `processedImage = preprocess_input(catImage)`? And maybe also `processedImage = preprocess_input(np.array(catImage))`?

Comment: I solved the error. It is generating output, 512 feature maps of size 8x8. How can I enlarge the size of feature map from 8 x 8 to 128 x 128?

Comment: You can't, unless you want to see huge squares. The output is that size. (VGG has a lot of `MaxPooling2D` layers that gradually reduce the size of the output images).

Comment: You can try a bigger input image, if you ensure that your input shape is `(None, None, 3)` when creating the VGG.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. The solution worked for me. Now, my 50 is yours :D

Comment: can you explain how we can apply `saveOrPlot(featureMap)`? I tried different codes but I could not save the image.

Comment: You can save the numpy arrays, you can use image libraries such as PIL, cv2 and others.

Comment: I tried ` plt.imsave('test.png', featureMap)`, But I got an error Invalid dimensions for image data

Comment: You need images, probably with shapes (x,y), (x,y,3) or (x,y,4). Keras will be probably working with batches, like (batch, x, y) or (batch, x, y, channels). You must select and reshape properly.